# Problem while installing eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, java, eclipse, jdk

**Been trying to install the lastest version of Eclipse from the official website, but whenever I begin installing the IDE, an error occurs. I've already tried to uninstall completely all the java versions and made sure to reinstall JDK-11.**

**I'm on Ubuntu 20.10;**

**These are the error logs:**

```
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] OpenJDK Runtime Environment 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.10
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.2020-12
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.18.0.v20200820-0414, build=4919, branch=f78238ba11ce04fb6bb89f0cb98f4dd759377d1d
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.18.0.v20200624-1156, build=4919, branch=f78238ba11ce04fb6bb89f0cb98f4dd759377d1d
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.16.0.v20200814-1205, build=4919, branch=f78238ba11ce04fb6bb89f0cb98f4dd759377d1d
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (2020-12))
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Offline = false
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Mirrors = true
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Resolving 17 requirements from 3 repositoriesto /home/manuel/java-2020-124/eclipse
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:epp.package.java [4.18.0,5.0.0)
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.18.0,5.0.0)
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.18.0,5.0.0)
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.lemminx.feature.feature.group
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.editors_feature.feature.group
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tips.feature.feature.group
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.xml.feature.feature.group
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2020-12/202012101200
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12/202012161000
[2021-01-21 23:02:59] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2021-01-21 23:03:01] Calculating requirements and dependencies.
[2021-01-21 23:03:01] Computing prerequisite plan
[2021-01-21 23:03:02] Collecting 1 artifacts from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2020-12/202012101200
[2021-01-21 23:03:02] Downloading epp.package.java.executable.gtk.linux.x86_64
[2021-01-21 23:03:02] Collected 1 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2020-12/202012101200 in 0.002s
[2021-01-21 23:03:02] Collecting 3 artifacts from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12/202012161000
[2021-01-21 23:03:03] Downloading org.eclipse.platform_root
[2021-01-21 23:03:03] Downloading org.eclipse.rcp_root
[2021-01-21 23:03:03] Downloading org.eclipse.platform.ide.executable.gtk.linux.x86_64
[2021-01-21 23:03:03] Collected 3 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12/202012161000 in 0.471s
[2021-01-21 23:03:03] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
[2021-01-21 23:03:03] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:291)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:551)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:343)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:899)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3828)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3756)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3737)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3630)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1156)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=_home_manuel_java-2020-124_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
  java.util.zip.ZipException: Exception in opening zip file: /home/manuel/.p2/pool/plugins/ch.qos.logback.classic_1.2.3.v20200428-2012.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3828)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3737)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3630)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1156)
  Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1567)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1375)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1469)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1274)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1237)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:727)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:844)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:247)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3828)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3737)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3630)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
    ... 1 more

[2021-01-21 23:03:03]
```

Comment: Does the software run on this version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Yep, I checked on the website and it says that it should be compatible. For now I'm sticking with the one from the Store, but it's an old version;